# Mapping of two GET-Parameters to speaking URL with RouteEnhancers won't work correctly

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm having some trouble with RouteEnhancers on a TYPO3 site.

I have two GET-Parameters which I want to map to a speaking url. I have the parameters contrast and bigfont.

If contrast is set to 1 I would like to append a /kontrast to the url. 
If bigfont is set to 1 I would like to append a /bigfont to the url. 
If both are set to 1, both url-segments should be added (/kontrast/bigfont)

I tried to configure a RouteEnhancer for each of them like:

```
Kontrast:
    type: Simple
    routePath: '/{contrast}'
    defaults:
      contrast: '0'
    aspects:
      contrast:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          kontrastmodus: '1'
  GrosseSchrift:
    type: Simple
    routePath: '/{bigfont}'
    defaults:
      bigfont: '0'
    aspects:
      bigfont:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          bigfont: '1'
```

This works if only one of both is set to one (/kontrast or /bigfont is appended to the url). But if both are set to 1 it will use normal GET-Parameters again.

So I tried to configure both in one RouteEnhancer:

```
KontrastGrosseSchrift:
    type: Simple
    routePath: '/{contrast}/{bigfont}'
    defaults:
      bigfont: '0'
      contrast: '0'
    aspects:
      bigfont:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          bigfont: '1'
      contrast:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          kontrast: '1'
```

This works for only contrast set to 1 (/kontrast is appended), but bigfont isn't working at all. 
If only bigfont is set to 1 it will append /0/bigfont (the /0 shouldn't be there), if both are set to 1 it will append /kontrast/bigfont (like it should), but in both cases a '*Page not Found*' Error is thrown.

Can anyone help me configure this correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure. But, Try adding `requirements:` to your `yaml` this could work for you. Give it try. [See configuration here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#simple-enhancer)

Comment: using requirements helped, I can access the page correctly with all three url-possibillities if I use all three setups above with added requirements.
But now the link generation in the FE when both parameters are set to 1 isn't working correctly. I use <f:link.page additionalParams="{contrast:0}" addQueryString="1"> to unset contrast, but it will output the url like site.de/0/1 (if it was site.de/kontrast/bigfont/ before). Any idea's on that?

Comment: If your issue has resolved, you can post as answer and close this. This will help others too! After all, sharing is caring!!

Comment: Sorry, edited the comment above. Link generation in FE isn't working properly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as TYPO3 Core would never know when building a URL with both GET arguments, which one should be used first.

`/my-page/0/1` <- which one should be which parameter? This happens if both arguments are optional, so `/my-page/0` would be ambiguous as both values would be possible. TYPO3's Routing component cannot determine (also when building a URL) which one should be which.

Of course, it is fully possible to build a custom Enhancer for TYPO3 which would solve your needs.

I guess you're even looking for a "decorator" (such as the PageType decorator) concept, where this is not really bound to a plugin or something similar, but site-wide. So a custom "Decorator" would be the solution I'd say.

Just for completeness: The SimpleEnhancer and PluginEnhancer can handle multiple parameters but only if the properties are in a defined order and shipped properly.